# what is the government responsible for making new rules called?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is the ministry of interior, ministry of defense etc. However I want to know the name of the sector of the government/ministry which makes new rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *[Legislature](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/legislature)* is an officially elected or otherwise selected body of people vested with the responsibility and power to make laws for a political unit, such as a state or nation.

Comment: ... and enforced by the [judiciary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judiciary).

Comment: @NigelJ No, interpreted by the judiciary, enforced by the executive.

Comment: @choster The _judgement_ is an interpretation and, agreed, the _punishment_ is executed. 'Enforcement' is  by both judgment _and_ punishment, I would have thought.

Comment: Laws are made by the legislature.  Rules, or regulations, are made by the various departments of the executive branch, and must be consistent with the law they are meant to implement.   If a regulation is deemed illegal by someone affected by it, he can sue the department, and then the judiciary hears the case; in the US, the Supreme Court may eventually become involved.

Comment: @ab2 Good point -- the question looks like it could equally be about regulatory bodies under ministerial control, instead of legislative bodies. Question needs to be clarified.